# How to get iTunes on BackTrack 5?

Tags: backtrack

Hey everyone in the backtrack community, this is probably the most unique question ever asked for bt. I am attempting to get "iTunes" on backtrack for internet use on a lan, you know similarly to windows, uses a USB connection to pass along the traffic, and the phone is used through iTunes as a personal hotspot. I also know that I can broadcast this from the phone but id much rather do it over the USB for security. Anyone know something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to run ITunes on GNU/Linux. You have a lot of opensource softwares that now handle ipod and iphone. And if you succesfully install ITunes on GNU/Linux I'm not sure you'll be able to connect to your phone through the phone.

This is an [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPhone_Tethering), but they explain which softwares you need to install and how to connect to your Phone through the usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are two issues going on here.

> I am attempting to get "iTunes" on backtrack

Because iTunes has not been compiled for linux operating systems, you will need to use an emulator program. The most popular being 'wine'

iTunes currently has a 'garbage' rating for wine.
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347

However that begs two questions

1. Are you using backtrack as your primary OS? If so, that is a bad idea. Because backtrack runs as root, it is only intend to be used for short periods of time. I find it best to run backtrack inside a Virtual Machine.
2. Why do you need iTunes to get internet access?
   iTunes is not required to get internet access to your laptop. You can enable your phone to be a mobile 'hotspot', and then connect your laptop to the wireless AP. If you are doing wireless penetration testing, then you should have two network cards.

   A wireless card that supports promiscuous mode (such as the [alpha s036](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/alfa-usb-wifi-awus036nha)).  and your built in ethernet or built in wireless for internet.

Update:
If you want to do usb tethering with your iPhone, see the following blog:
http://www.howtogeek.com/68999/how-to-tether-your-iphone-to-your-linux-pc/

Comment: Please re-read the question before posting, I answered both questions in my own question.

Comment: Updated answer. You will need to install ipheth-utils.